# HTML Multiple spaces Alignment

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I want there rows alignment by col, I write the code:

```
result.seq_content = 'GCAUCCGGGUUGAGGUAGUAG'
result.vel_bar =     '|| ||||||  ||| ||| ||'
result.seq_match =   'CG.AGGUUC..UUC.AUC.UC'
<table style="font-family:Courier, monospace;">
<td>
    {{ result.seq_content}}
    <br>
    {{ result.vel_bar}}
    <br>
    {{ result.seq_match}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But the result is 
[image]

Multiple spaces become a space.

I used tag pre, but the size of A, C, G, U is not equal to the size of | or space, so it failed.

I changed the code:

```
result.seq_content = 'GCAUCCGGGUUGAGGUAGUAG'
result.vel_bar =     '|| ||||||  ||| ||| ||'
result.seq_match =   'CG.AGGUUC..UUC.AUC.UC'
<table style="font-family:Courier, monospace;">
<tr>
    <td>
    {{ result.seq_content}}
    <br>
    {% for e in result.vel_bar %}
        {% if e == ' '%}
            &nbsp
        {% else%}
            {{ e}}
        {% endif%}
    {% endfor%}
    <br>
    {{ result.seq_match}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But the size of {{ e}} is bigger than A, C, G, U.

So how could I align multiple spaces, like this:

```
GCAUCCGGGUUGAGGUAGUAG
|| ||||||  ||| ||| ||
CG.AGGUUC..UUC.AUC.UC
```

Thanks! :D

**The problem has been solved.**

**I replaced all ' ' with nbsp;, and cancel the automatic escape, this is my code:**

```
result.vel_bar = result.vel_bal.repalce(' ', '&nbsp;')

<td align="left">
{{ result.seq_content }}
{% autoescape false%}
{{ result.vel_bar}}
{% endautoescape %}
{{ result.seq_match }}
</td>
```

Thank you for help. :D

Comment: Show the HTML and CSS code of your best effort, which is probably one using `pre`. The way the code is generated is irrelevant here. What matters is what makes the browser use a non-monospace font inside `pre`, where the *default* is monospace.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I do not have any CSS code, and the HTML code is sample as this. I use the tag `pre`, the demo is not work. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ewR54/11/

Comment: The jsfiddle looks ok, the same as in the “like this” part in the question. Are you using some special settings in your browser? (It is possible to set the browser default for monospace font to a non-monospace font.)

Comment: Yes, it is my browser problem, it works in my friend browser. But I use Chrome default settings, and it also did not work in my FireFox, Opera. Maybe is the Ubuntu13.04 setting problem. BTW, thank u! :D @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: If it happens on different browsers, then my guess is that they are set to use a default monospace font that is somehow broken. Check in the browser settings what that font is and then inspect the font (especially the width of a space) e.g. in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it was good to use a monospace font. HTML replaces multiple spaces to a single one: but you can replace each space with `&nbsp;` 
`result.vel_bar.replaceAll(/\s/, '&nbsp;')`
This way your alignment should be perfect.

Comment: result.vel_bar.replaceAll(/\s/, '&nbsp;') will not print space, but print &nbsp

Comment: Indeed: and `&nbsp;` in HTML will cause the Browser to insert a protected space there... That will cause the monospaced text to align perfectly.

Comment: I canceled the autoescape, then solve the problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can break those sequence elements using some php/js/python arrays and then build it up using php/js/python using the css classes that make it happen: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ewR54/5/

So basically you parse your data:

```
GACU
||||
CUGA ..

^--Parser -->
```

and for each sequence you take the 3 elements out (ex: G, |, C) and build it using php, js or python using the div construction in that fiddle I posted.

Have fun.

Comment: If I take the 3 elements out for each sequence, then the each element size will increase. So if there a lot of element in each sequence, a line can not show all elements.

Comment: i dont really understand what you are referring to. A sequence has only 3 elements, you take them out to parse them and add the according html for each element, then print them out as a string. Given that you have the html constructed right and that your html file points to the css file, the browser will build the sequence for you. This also gives you a lot of flexibility if you want to color each element and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<pre>` tag in `<td>`

```
    <pre>
    'GCAUCCGGGUUGAGGUAGUAG'
    '|| ||||||  ||| ||| ||'
    'CG.AGGUUC..UUC.AUC.UC'    
    </pre>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ewR54/7/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank u, it is my browser problem. :D

Comment: ahh.. nice that you cracked it..:)